# How to fix one person as a reviewer every time a pull request is raised in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I want myself to be a fixed reviewer for one project, i.e., every time anyone wants to merge to master while creating a pull request, I should be already fixed as a reviewer.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in the [branch policy configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers):

> If you select Required next to a path entry, then the pull request cannot be completed until:
>
> - Every user added as a reviewer for the path approves the changes.
> - At least one person in every group added to the path approves the changes.

Look at the image for more details:

[image]

Comment: Actually I am aware of this process. What my requirement is that whenever any of my teammate raise a pull request, I should already be there in the reviewer list irrespective of who is raising the pull request for the project. I need my id to be already present there in the reviewer list.

Comment: @Mudit that's exactly what the `Add automatic reviewers` policy is all about. I've edited my answer to explicitly highlight the image from the docs. If you set `*` as `Paths` and choose `Required`, any pull request created by anyone in that repo will automatically contain your account as required reviewer.

Comment: I can confirm that's exactly what it's needed for